# How does `go build` decide which subdirectories to build when it is not given specific packages to build?

Tags: go

I have recently noticed that `go build -a` will build almost all, but not all packages in the subdirectories of my `$GOPATH`.

What algorithm does `go build` use to decide what to build?

The [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) for the `go` command did not specify, or I misread it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no path is specified, the 'go build' command builds the package in the current directory. The documentation is [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_package_lists).

The 'go build' command also builds any out of date dependencies.